# how to make user-select work for Safari browser

Tags: css, safari

I am having this html structure:

```
<ol class="linenums">
   <li class="L0">
      <code>
          <span><!-- piece of code--></span>
      </code>
   </li>
</ol>
```

Before the code, there are line numbers.
By selecting the code, i use this css so that only the code is selected and not the linenumbers

```
ol.linenums li {
-user-select: none;
-webkit-user-select: none; /* Chrome/Safari */        
-moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
-ms-user-select: none; /* IE10+ */
} 
ol.linenums li code {
-user-select: all;
-webkit-user-select: all; /* Chrome/Safari */        
-moz-user-select: all; /* Firefox */
-ms-user-select: all; /* IE10+ */
}
```

In every browser (IE, FF, Chrome, Opera), only the code is selected. Except in 
Safari; it is impossible to select anything at all.

How can i make this work for Safari?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable text selection highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/how-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting)

Answer (score 14):

It seems that Safari needs this line also:

```
-webkit-user-select: text;
```

So it's working now with this code:

```
ol.linenums li code {
  user-select: all;
  -webkit-user-select: text; /* Safari fallback only */
  -webkit-user-select: all; /* Chrome/Safari */
  -moz-user-select: all; /* Firefox */
  -ms-user-select: all; /* IE10+ */
}
```

Comment: For people like me, checking the current state: [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_user-select) confirms that as of 2021 `-webkit-` prefix is still required on safari and edge and `all` is not supported