# Exclude element from copied text in Safari

Tags: html, css, safari, textselection

I want users to be able to copy-paste a block of text without also getting inline controls, like buttons.

In Chrome, applying `user-select: none;` to the controls accomplishes this. If the user selects the whole paragraph, the buttons are excluded from the selection, and copying gives you only the content.

In Safari, using `-webkit-user-select: none;`, the selection visually shows that the buttons aren’t selected, but copy-pasting still includes their content.

Here’s a demo. The goal is that selecting everything then copying gets “13”, not “123”.

```css
button {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
1<button>2</button>3
```

Also doesn’t work: putting the content in a shadow DOM.

Probably works, but I’m hoping for better: make the text an SVG, or contort the DOM so the buttons are inline only visually, not in the DOM.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to make user-select work for Safari browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34372056/how-to-make-user-select-work-for-safari-browser)

Comment: @MrUpsidown no, the issue there is Safari property value support. However, the asker uses `user-select` differently than I assumed, which I think answers my question; I’ll answer it myself if it works out.

Comment: @MrUpsidown the solution there doesn’t also solve this, either they weren’t asking about copy-pasting, like this question, or Safari has changed since then.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is using `::before` or `::after`. With a little CSS, you can keep content edits inline, too.

```css
button::after {
  content: attr(data-content);
}
```

```html
1<button data-content="2"></button>3
```

This has the major limitation of not supporting a full DOM tree, just text or an image.

I don’t know if this works with screen readers.